# nodemailer: message queued but not sent

Tags: email, smtp, nodemailer

I am working with nodemailer to send email using custom SMTP server.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'my.smtp.host',
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: 'user',
    pass: 'password',
  },
  debug: true,
  logger: true
})

let info = await transporter.sendMail({
  from: from,
  to: to,
  subject: subject,
  text: content,
  html: content,
  cc: cc,
  bcc: bcc,
})
```

Following is the result of sendMail.

```
{
  accepted: [
    'to@to.com'
  ],
  rejected: [],
  envelopeTime: 39,
  messageTime: 49,
  messageSize: 1730,
  response: '250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 5513B432BE6',
  envelope: {
    from: 'from@from.com',
    to: [
      'to@to.com'
    ]
  },
  messageId: '<274421c8-1abd-4973-dd8e-f57285b46a70@from.com>'
}
```

And following is log message.

```
...
[2021-06-09 19:00:21] INFO  [StdWZWNkAto] <1730 bytes encoded mime message (source size 1693 bytes)>
[2021-06-09 19:00:21] DEBUG [StdWZWNkAto] S: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 5513B432BE6
[2021-06-09 19:00:21] DEBUG [StdWZWNkAto] Closing connection to the server using "end"
```

I already tested this SMTP server with other tools and it works correctly.
What's wrong?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this means that nodemailer successfully send the email and now it is in the queue of your custom SMTP server, so you have to deal with it. For instance, `sendmail` allows to see the queue via `mailq` command and resend via `sendmail -q` (or `sendmail -q -v` for more information). If you need more details, you should provide info about your SMTP server.